# How can I create reusable "functions" composed of tasks that can be called multiple times in playbooks with different arguments/variables?

Tags: ansible

I have a some sets of tasks that I find myself repeating frequently in my playbooks.

Say that I have a set of three tasks that need to be performed, in order, multiple times, but with a different argument or variable. The tasks for the first variable must be completed before the tasks for the second variable can be run and so-on. Something like this:

```yaml
# Run three tasks for Var 1
- name: Task 1 for Var 1
  shell: |
    <Do something here>
- name: Task 2 for Var 1
  shell: |
    <Do something here>
- name: Task 3 for Var 1
  shell: |
    <Do something here>

# Do the same tasks again for Var 2
- name: Task 1 for Var 2
  shell: |
    <Do something here>
- name: Task 2 for Var 2
  shell: |
    <Do something here>
- name: Task 3 for Var 2
  shell: |
    <Do something here>
```

How can I bundle the set of three tasks as a function-like thing that can be called multiple times with different arguments or variables?

Is this best achieved using roles that I call via `include_role`?

It looks like `import_role` is the wrong solution for this since it is parsed when the playbook is run, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `include_role` to call a common function and `vars` to supply arguments to the common role. Optionally you can use `when` condition to call the function if conditionally required. Also to expose the registers created within the task for further execution of the playbook you can use `public: yes` while including the role.

Following is one example calling a role called `common_role` which take two arguments `argument_1` and `argument_2` which will be always called(`true`) and the registers would be exposed for entire play.

```yaml
- name: "Calling Common Role"
   include_role:
     name: common_role
     public: yes
   vars:
     argument_1: "foo"
     argument_2: "bar"
   when: True
```

Now the same role(`common_role`) can be called again with different set of arguments.

```yaml
- name: "Calling Common Role"
   include_role:
     name: common_role
     public: yes
   vars:
     argument_1: "hey"
     argument_2: "there"
   when: True
```

More Read: [Official Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The one part I'm not sure I understand is the part about using `public` to expose the "registers". I'm not familiar with the term "registers" in this context. Does "registers" refer to the set of variables available to the role? Are they private to the role by default so that setting `vars` doesn't have an impact on the included role unless `public` is set to "yes"?

Comment: you get it right, registers are like variables. By default, if you store something in registers their scope is limited to that role only. Now, if you try to access those variables/registers in the next role or the remaining portion of the play then they would be not available. That's where `public: true` comes in picture.

Comment: You can read more in the official documentation , located at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-public